# Http request doesn't load as soon the angular view loads

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I load the data from Firebase, but only every secend time or so the data is shown in the view, but also only if I refresh.Sometimes even when i refresh fist at the second time.  When i switch views in the app the data isn't shown at all..

What's my mistake?

```
.controller('CatsCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http) {

  $scope.init = function() {

  var ref = firebase.database().ref("Entries");
  ref.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      $scope.tmp = snapshot.val();
      $scope.data = $scope.tmp.kategorienamen

    });

  }


})
```

HTML

```
<ion-view ng-init="init()">
    <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-top no-bgColor">
  <h1 class="title-top">Kategorien</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" class="has-header has-footer bg" scroll="true">

    <div ng-repeat="cat in data" class="animated lightSpeedIn">
      <a nav-transition="none"><div ng-style="{'background': 'url(' + cat.bgurl + ')','background-repeat': 'no-repeat','background-size': 'cover','display': 'block','width': '100%','height': '25vh' }" class="bgcat center">
        <div class="inner">
          <h1>{{cat}}</h1>
          <h4>{{}}</h4>
        </div>
      </div></a>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Problem is that you are overwriting watched variable. You could either use scope.apply to enforce refreshing the view or use directive, so it will return some content after performing request. Either of these method is not a pure solution, as the best would be to use native angular's request method so it would rerender after its done on its own.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin a cat but here is one and you should read about the rest of them

```
$scope.data = ref.once("value");
```

Edit: As suggested .once returns a promise already https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/once.html

Comment: Almost: `ref.once()` returns a promise, so the proper form is `$scope.data = ref.once("value");`;

Comment: Thank you! Could you share a link?